# Server-side Validation of Kubernetes yaml

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to do server-side validation of Kubernetes yaml files before applying them.

I know that in my Jenkins agent, I could use the following kubectl command for validating yaml files at the server-side but I am a bit concerned about access-control:

- Kubernetes < v1.18:
  `kubectl apply --server-dry-run -f ...`
- Kubernetes >= v1.18:
  `kubectl apply --dry-run=server -f ...`

The Kubernetes documentation says the following:

> Authorization for dry-run and non-dry-run requests is identical. Thus,
> to make a dry-run request, the user must be authorized to make the
> non-dry-run request.

I don't want any Jenkins agents to have super powers over my EKS cluster. A bad actor could use my Jenkins agent maliciously and apply any manifests they wanted. Right now for security/stability/management reasons, creating Kubernetes objects is done by a different system not Jenkins.

I checked a few other options but I can see drawbacks:

- Kubeval is not aware of any CRDs installed in the actual cluster.
- Client Validation is not really end-to-end validation
- I could develop a rest api that exposes a validation rest endpoint and hits Kubernetes APIs or runs a kubectl `--run-dry` under the hood. However, this requires more dev work than we have capacity for.

Do you have any ideas or are you aware of any validation tools that I could use in our CI system securely for the purpose of validating end-2-end Kubernetes yaml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for this myself and did not find a sufficient tooling. However, there are few workarounds:

- Deploy all objects to a *temporary* `ci-job-id` namespace in dev/stage clusters. They should be the same as a prod, but will not impose the security risks you mentioned. This gives an additional benefit - you can check if everything got created, all pods are running. It helps to catch issues like insufficient resource requests, missing images, misconfigured `Service` selectors, etc. Also it let's you add a smoke test on top.
- Spin a small minikube with all the CRDs specifically for CI validations. This approach gives you less coverage, but it is much cheaper to maintain.

Comment: Hey Max, thank you for your answer! I would like to validate the manifest before deploying anything to any cluster so the first option won't work. I am planning to use Dev for catching issues. The validation step is more about catching errors before the deployment happens (as it's time consuming).
I haven't thought of the second option though! I will have a look but I guess the minikube thingie won't mimic closely my dev cluster right?

Comment: If you have all CRDs applied - it will. Even if there are no controllers for those CRDs, it will not affect the validation

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what I wanted to do initially is not feasible. Applying server-side validation on a manifest containing objects with dependencies (e.g a Namespace and a Deployment)is not possible. See [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83562) issue.

As a result, client side validation is the solution moving forward. Either it is with Kubeval or any other client-side mechanism. Kubeval won't validate CRDs but there is away of ignoring them so that the validation does not fail:

> Currently kubeval relies on schemas generated from the Kubernetes API.
> This means it's not possible to validate resources using CRDs.
> Currently you need to pass a flag to ignore missing schemas, though
> this may change in a future major version.

Answer (score 1):

client-side validation (with `kubectl --dry-run`) has little value because it is missing some trivial [schema misconfigurations](https://github.com/datreeio/kubernetes-schema-validation#misconfigurations-coverage-summary).

you will get better results if you will perform the validation with **kubeval** (as you mentioned, you can skip CRDs) or you can use **kubeconform** that has [CRD support](https://github.com/yannh/kubeconform/blob/2e7c2bfe33c298c29c23a92cadf8712f33b09121/Readme.md#overriding-schemas-location---crd-and-openshift-support).